# How to pass current rowID to CopyOrMoveRowDirective statement using C# and the Smartsheet-API?

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have code in C# that moves a row from one sheet to another, but I can only get it to work when I hard code the row id in the `CopyOrMoveRowDirective` line.

What is the syntax for passing a row id into the statement?  I have tried `rowm.ID` in place of `80233296095108`, but i get a syntax error.

Here is a simplified version of the code, but need to pass in the current rowid as I loop through.

```
foreach (Row rowm in sheet.Rows)

{

       {

          CopyOrMoveRowDestination destination = new CopyOrMoveRowDestination { SheetId = 336102784558980 };

          CopyOrMoveRowDirective directive = new CopyOrMoveRowDirective { RowIds = new long[] { 80233296095108 }, To = destination };

          CopyOrMoveRowResult results = smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.MoveRowsToAnotherSheet(3267158118557572, directive, null, null);

       }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After much trial and error, I have it working.  It took 1 additional line of code and a change to the CopyOrMoveRowDirective line.  I added long rowmId = rowm.Id.Value; as a new line of code.  And then updated CopyOrMoveRowDirective directive = new CopyOrMoveRowDirective { RowIds = new long[] { rowmId }, To = destination };

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got this working. Have you tried doing the same declaration within the CopyOrMoveRowDirective? Instead of doing a new line you could try RowIds = new long[] { rowm.Id.Value } when you are declaring your directive variable.